# If X,Y,Z are independent standard normal random variables, find the distribution of X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, spherical-coordinates

> If $X,Y,Z$ are independent standard normal random variables, find the distribution of $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2$. Using spherical coordinates.

My doubt appears in that last sentence, how can I use spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distribution of $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2$ is uniquely determined by the cumulative distribution function it corresponds. To find this, we must find
$$P(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 \leq t)$$
for some constant $t$. From here, it depends on how you parametrize spherical coordinates in your course. I am accustomed to taking $\phi$ from $- \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, though some people take it from $- \pi$ to $\pi$. In the way that I'll be doing it, we must account for a factor of $r^2 \cos \phi$.

Since $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$ in spherical coordinates, $r$ will range from $0$ to $\sqrt{t}$. Then $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $\phi$ from $- \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. The integral is then: 
$$P(X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2 \leq t) = \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi} \int_{\phi = - \frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_{r=0}^{\sqrt{t}} f_{X,Y,Z} (\mathbf{\vec{v}}) r^2 \cos \phi \; dr d\phi d\theta,$$
where $f_{X,Y,Z} (\mathbf{\vec{v}})$ is the joint density of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$. Since $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are independent, this is the product of the marginal densities. This may lookg rather messy at first, but the conversion to spherical cleans up the integrand quite nicely.

This will give the CDF of $X^2 + Y^2 + Z^2$, from which you can read off its distribution. I'll let you finish it from here.

What you'll find eventually is that this distribution is chi-square with three degrees of freedom. Generally speaking, 
$$X_1^2 + X_2^2 + \ldots + X_n^2 \sim \chi(n)$$
where the $X_i$ are i.i.d. standard normal random variables.

Comment: I don't get any term in $\phi$ besides $cos\phi$, so it becomes $0$ in the integral, so am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Integrating $\cos \phi$ from $- \frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ should give $2$. The final answer that I get is $\frac{\sqrt{t} e^{-x/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Comment: Certainly! I must have gotten something wrong. Now I have issues with computing the last integral $\int_0^{\sqrt t}r^2e^{-r^2/2}dr$. By performing integration by parts I get to the error function which doesn't have an antiderivative to evaluate at the extremes

Comment: Yes, that derivative isn't defined by elementary functions, but you can differentiate it using the second fundamental theorem of calculus to get the density function. (Sorry, I should have been clear that my final answer above was for the density function.)