# Finding the distribution of $X^2 +Y^2 + Z^2$

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

> If $X, \ Y,\ Z$ are independent standard normal random variables, I'm trying to find the distribution of $X^2 +Y^2 + Z^2$ using spherical coordinates.

Taking $$x=rsin\theta \cos\phi, \ \ y = rsin\theta \sin\phi, \ \ z = cos\theta$$

$$r \in [0,\sqrt t] \ \ \theta \in [0, \pi] \ \ \phi \in [0,2\pi] $$

I'm going to compute the cdf to be able to tell afterwards which distribution it follows.

Therefore after using that the joint pdf becomes the product of marginals because of independence we get

$$ P(X^2 +Y^2 + Z^2 \leq t) = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^{\sqrt t}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}e^{-r^2/2}r^2sin\theta drd\theta d\phi = \int_0^{\sqrt t}\frac{2}{(2\pi)^{1/2}}e^{-r^2/2}r^2 dr$$ but here, I don't know how to compute this integral.

Comment: You could aim for the density, which would require to replace $r^2$ by something like $s$.  Since $\frac{ds}{dr}=2r$ you should end up with something proportional to $s^{1/2}e^{-s/2}$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? I don't really get what you're implying

Comment: What's the point of [reposting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3647476/321264) this question? Just edit your old post if you have further queries.

Comment: It was closed so I thought I had to post a new one with more details.

Comment: No that is not the recommended course of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1, ..., X_n$ are i.i.d. standard Gaussians then the distribution of $X_1^2 + ... + X_n^2$ is known as the $\chi_n^2$-distribution. Calculating the cdf of the $\chi^2$ distributions is quite involved and includes special functions. See the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) page for more information.